# Joining to numpy in a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am unable to join data with the calculated values WLD1. So my data is 200 X 3. After adding the calculated WLD1 and adding it as a column in data I need a 200 x 4 dimension dataset. I get a column of values for WLD1 but I am unable to join it to data. I get dimensionality error.

Please do help me out.

Have a 200X3 data set. Please find the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N = 200
mean = [180,200,400]
cov = [[0.3, 0.2, 0.1],[0.2, 0.2, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.4]]
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, N)
for i in data:
    wLD1 = np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(i - mean), np.linalg.inv(cov)), (i - mean))
```

Comment: Join what exacly? I see one numpy array (`data`) only, which is the second one? Please be more clear. What is your expected result? What are you trying to do exaclty?

Comment: I really can't understand what you want to achieve and what is blocking you from achieving it :/ Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Edited the question, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: It's better yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your variable `wLD1` is a float and not an array, therefore, you cannot concatenate it to your data.

What you can do is :

```
mean = np.array(mean)
cov = np.array(cov)
wLD1 = np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(data - mean), np.linalg.inv(cov)), (data - mean))
```

And then, you will have `wLD1` as an array of shape 200. You will be able to concatenate it to your data.

Comment: Then I get this error; shapes (3,200) and (3,3) not aligned: 200 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)